# android studio DataBinding Build Error

Tags: android, data-binding

I am testing Android new feature DataBinding.
My Android studio version is 1.5.1

so I followed the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/data-binding/guide.html#data_binding_layout_files).

after this step:

```
android {
    ....
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Android studio Build raised an Error,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsDebug'.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError (no error message)
```

I don't know what is going on, so any one has a work around?

Comment: I create a new blank project ,and add dataBinding{enable = true},then press run,and the error just araised.

Comment: Do you have jcenter as a maven repository?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you use SQLDelight? I ran into this problem today. Apparently there is currently a conflict where you cannot use both Data Binding and SQLDelight, although it should be fixed soon.
https://github.com/square/sqldelight/issues/123

An important debugging note for mysterious problems like this with no clear error message: do your Gradle build from the command line or Terminal pane in Android Studio.
Mac:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

PC:

```
gradlew.bat assembleDebug --stacktrace
```

You can also try the --info or --debug flags. Using these commands you can get much more information which can help when Googling for an answer.